# Custom modal is displaying despite condition not met in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On my log in page I want to show a modal with a picture when a failed login attempt is made.

in my `render()` I have this exert:

```
<ToggleDisplay show={this.state.failedLogin} tag="section">
    <Lightbox show={this.state.failedLogin} mainSrc={pic}  hideOnOverlayClicked 
    </Lightbox>
</ToggleDisplay>
```

The problem I'm having is the picture is shown when the page is loaded even though show=false by default. How do I have the picture display only when show=true?

Comment: use css to make display : none

Comment: please provide more information. For example Lightbox and ToggleDisplay code

Answer (score 0):

How about doing like this:

```
{ this.state.failedLogin && (
 <ToggleDisplay tag="section">
   <Lightbox show={this.state.failedLogin} mainSrc={pic}  
     hideOnOverlayClicked 
   </Lightbox>
 </ToggleDisplay>
)}
```